# Installing Wxpython on mac

Tags: macos, python-2.7, wxpython

I am trying to install wxpython on mac os. I have already tried following solution. I have already enables software installation from all sources

a) Downloaded the binary for mac and tried to install it. It says no software found to install at the last step.

b) I tried using brew to install. The brew command works find but when when I tried import wx it says no module found.

Can you specify how to get rid of this error? My mac version is 10.11.5 I am using python 2.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the installer found here: https://wxpython.org/snapshots/. It is a current (as of 2 weeks ago) snapshot of the code, modified to use the newer Installer Package format.

Comment: It went through installation fine. But then I went into python and import wx gives the same error as earlier.

Comment: Check which python binary you are running, like this: `python -c "import sys; print(sys.prefix)"`. That wxPython installer should work with either Apple's Python (with a prefix of `/usr` or `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7`)  and the Python from python.org (with prefix `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7`)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually I had miniconda installed. While trying to install wxpython on one of the links it gave a command using conda so I installed miniconda for it. uninstalled it now and it works with apple python. I guess a lot of people have this problem. :)